# NodePort in Openshift is not working

Tags: openshift

Deployed single node cluster with `oc`

```
$ sudo oc cluster up --public-hostname=$PUBLIC_IP
$ oc version
oc v3.7.14
kubernetes v1.7.6+a08f5eeb62
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO
```

Added `allowHostPorts: true` in `oc edit scc restricted`'s config.

Deployed an application with `NodePort` config

```
tiger-dev         172.30.30.215   <nodes>       8080:30111/TCP            10d
```

I was not able to access the application with `$NODEIP:30111`, but I can see the traffic coming into the node and NOT going out.

### Update1

iptables rules -> https://pastebin.com/NPeZM26W

```
$ sudo iptables-save | grep 30111
-A KUBE-NODEPORTS -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/tiger-dev:http" -m tcp --dport 30111 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-NODEPORTS -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/tiger-dev:http" -m tcp --dport 30111 -j KUBE-SVC-PPQAPMXK5BHYARPU
```

Comment: Could you post your iptables rules? Use `iptables-save`.

Comment: @ccshih Please check my update1 in the question